# How to send a file from cloud storage using response.sendFile in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a response back to a client using an http trigger from firebase cloud functions.
When I sent the response using the file location from Cloud Storage, the sendFile method throws this error:

```
"path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

res.sendFile(obj.path(param1, param2, param3, param4));
```

obj.path(param1, param2, param3, param4) this builds a path to gs:// or an https:// with the params.

Then I decided to do this:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

exports.fun = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
let extResponse = await rp('firebase storage location');
          extResponse.pipe(res);
});
```

rp is now returning this error:

```
StatusCodeError: 403 - "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Permission denied. Could not perform this operation\"\n  }\n}"
```

This error is because cloud storage requires the request to be authenticated in order to let the service download the file from storage.

Is there a way to make this work and return the file back to the client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sendFile won't work, because it doesn't understand URLs.  It only understand files on the local filesystem.  You should be using the [Cloud Storage SDK for node](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/) to do this.   Create a [File](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File) object that points to the file you want to send, open up a read stream on it, then pipe the stream to the response:

```
const file = ... // whatever file you want to send
const readStream = file.createReadStream()
readStream.pipe(res)
```

Comment: I haven't been able to test what you wrote, but I'm sure this could help to fix the problem. As soon as I can test it I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: I do this same thing in a working project. I've borrowed the technique from other sample code. It'll work if you don't right.